# Bash function that will make sure that a number (n) is divisible by two other numbers (x) and (y)

Tags: bash, function

I'm trying to solve the following kata from codewars ([link](https://www.codewars.com/kata/is-n-divisible-by-x-and-y/train/shell)). But I keep getting the following error: `expected: "false" got: ""`.

So somehow I'm missing the arguments or something, or maybe I'm not returning correctly?

Instructions:

```
# Create a function isDivisible(n, x, y) that checks if a number n is 
# divisible by two numbers x AND y. All inputs are positive, non-zero 
# digits.

# Expected output:
isDivisible(12,2,6)--> true because 12 is divisible by 2 and 6
isDivisible(100,5,3)--> false because 100 is not divisible by 3
```

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function isDivisible () {
  if [ $(1 / 2) ] && [ $(1 / 2) ]
  then
    echo "true"
  else
    echo "false"
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the modulo `%` operator and check for the remainder. If its `0` then the number is divisible.

```
#!/bin/bash

isDivisible() {
    if (($1 % $2 == 0 && $1 % $3 == 0)); then
        echo "true"
    else
        echo "false"
    fi
}
```

```
$ isDivisible 12 2 6
true

$ isDivisible 100 5 3
false
```

Comment: @John Kugelman I'm still getting `Test Failed expected: "false" got: "" (compared using ==)` error ?

Comment: Codewars doesn't actually want the code wrapped in a function. Put the code at the top level and it passes.

Comment: note: that holds when you use bash as language, not for others